# Method for finding sum of series $\sum_{r = 1}^{10} \binom{10}{10 - r}\binom{20}{r}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this in a problem:
$$\sum_{r = 1}^{10} \binom{10}{10 - r}\binom{20}{r}$$
Please help me solve this and give a general method to solve such sums.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If the summation was from $r=0$ to $10$ you could apply Vandermonde's convolution formula: so add (and then subtract) the missing $r=0$ term

Comment: n C r is the same as n C (n-r) . Thus our problem is Sum(1 to n) (n C r) * ((2n) C r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a "general method", except learning how to interpret binomial coefficients, and sums and products of such.

For instance, $\binom{20}r$ may be interpreted as the number of ways to pick $r$ balls from a set of $20$ (distinguishable, numbered) balls. $\binom{10}{10-r}$ may be interpreted as picking $10-r$ balls from a different set of $10$ balls. Multiply them together, and you get the number of ways to pick $10$ balls with the condition that $r$ of those balls come from the set of $20$ (and $10-r$ of them come from the set of $10$). Sum over $r$ from $0$ to $10$, and you get the total number of ways to pick $10$ balls from the $20+10=30$ you have, without any restrictions. But this is exactly what $\binom{30}{10}$ counts. Since our sum counts the same thing as $\binom{30}{10}$, the two must be equal.

However, you're only summing from $r=1$ to $10$, so you need to subtract the $r=0$ term from the above result to get $$ \binom{30}{10}-\binom{10}{10}\binom{20}{0}=\binom{30}{10}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using $$(1+x)^{20} = \binom{20}{0}+\binom{20}{1}x+\binom{20}{2}x^2+\cdots\cdots +\binom{20}{20}x^{20}.........(1)$$

Similarly $$(1+x)^{10} = \binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}x^{10}+\binom{10}{2}x^{2}+\cdots \cdots \cdots+\binom{10}{10}x^{10}.....(2)$$

Now coeficients of $x^{10}$ in multiplication of $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$(1+x)^{20}\cdot (1+x)^{10} = \binom{20}{0}\cdot \binom{10}{10}+\binom{20}{1}\cdot \binom{10}{9}+\cdots \cdots +\binom{20}{10}\cdot \binom{10}{0}$$

So $$\binom{30}{10}-1 = \sum^{10}_{r=1}\binom{20}{r}\binom{10}{10-r}$$

Comment: But shouldn't 10C10 and 20C0 be excluded since r can't be 0?

Comment: i had already excluded it

Comment: In the last step.... multiplication...

Comment: And ... should we manually multiply, or any other way?

Comment: which is just Vandermonde convolution, minus 1 (the missing term r=0)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{r = 1}^{10}{10 \choose 10 - r}{20 \choose r}:\ ?}$

It's *convenient* to evaluate a most general result:
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}{n \choose n - r}{2n \choose r} & =
-1 + \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose r}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - r + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{n \choose n - r}}
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{2n \choose r}z^{r}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\pars{1 + z}^{2n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-1 +\ \underbrace{ \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{3n} \over z^{n + 1}}\
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{3n \choose n}} =\
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{-1 + {3n \choose n}}}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{n = 10}$:

$$
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\sum_{r = 1}^{10}{10 \choose 10 - r}{20 \choose r} = -1 + {30 \choose 10}} =
\color{#f00}{30,045,014}}
$$